# Having trouble training multidimensional data (4d numpy matrix) in sklearn and pybrain

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, scikit-learn, pybrain

I have am training an emotion recognition system that detects emotions through facial movement and I have a 4 dimensional matrix that I am trying to train. However, sklearn is not allowing me to train the matrix. What I am doing is that I am trying to classify each emotion by creating a set of videos

Features that makes up the 4D matrix:
Number of videos (and each video will be assigned emotion label)
Number of frames per video
Direction of the facial landmarks per frame
Speed of the facial landmarks per frame

The actual feature matrix I am trying to train:
The left side is the speed (hypotenuse between same facial landmark each frame)
The right side is direction (arctan of the x and y values of the same facial landmark each frame)

```
>> main.shape
(2, 17, 68, 2)
# 2 videos, 17 frames per video, 68 facial landmarks, 2 features (direction and speed)
>> main
array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[-1.        , -0.        ],
         [-1.        , -0.        ],
         [-1.        , -0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 1.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 3.16227766, -1.24904577],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 1.41421356, -0.78539816],
         [-1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [-2.        , -0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[-3.60555128, -0.5880026 ],
         [-2.23606798, -0.46364761],
         [-2.23606798, -0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [ 3.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 2.23606798,  0.46364761],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 2.82842712, -0.78539816],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 1.        ,  1.        ],
         [ 1.        ,  1.        ]],

        [[-1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [-2.23606798,  1.10714872],
         [-2.23606798,  1.10714872],
         [ 2.        ,  1.        ]]],


       [[[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[-1.        , -0.        ],
         [-1.        , -0.        ],
         [-1.        , -0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 1.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 3.16227766, -1.24904577],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 1.41421356, -0.78539816],
         [-1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [-2.        , -0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[-3.60555128, -0.5880026 ],
         [-2.23606798, -0.46364761],
         [-2.23606798, -0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [ 3.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 2.23606798,  0.46364761],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 2.82842712, -0.78539816],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         [ 2.23606798, -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 1.        ,  1.        ],
         [ 1.        ,  1.        ]],

        [[-1.41421356,  0.78539816],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [-2.23606798,  1.10714872],
         [-2.23606798,  1.10714872],
         [ 2.        ,  1.        ]]]])
```

Error I got from sklearn SVM:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 4)
```

I then tried to play around with a more simple 3D matrix to see if I can find a way around it, but it gave me the same error:

```
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> model = SVC()
>>> features = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[8,9],[10,11]]])
>>> features.shape
(2, 2, 2)
>>> labels = [1,2]
>>> model.fit(features,labels)
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)
```

And other sklearn algorithms (like Naive Bayes) give me similar errors saying that they only accept 2D matricies.

I figured that the problem was that not really with my implementation, but that SVM, Naive Bayes, and other ml algorithms in general cannot handle more than 2 dimensions of data.

I tried turning to neural networks in pybrain but I could not figure out a way to feed the matrix into a pybrain neural network.

I though of the possibility of using PCA or reconstructing the design of the matrix, but I would prefer to keep these features and the same dimensions and not mess around with them.

Is there any way, machine learning algorithm, or neural network that I can use in order to train a 4D matrix?

Comment: How would you interpret a 4D matrix input? In 2D, we know row is observation/instance whereas the columns are features. How would you interpret your other two dimensions?

Comment: A common way is to reshape your 4D matrix to 2D. A close example is to train an algo for image recognition where image has 3D (width, height, and RGB-color-mix). In order to feed this input matrix to sklearn algo, you can reshape to (width x height) x 3-RGB-color.

Comment: I was considering on just combining the three features into one vector, but the problem is that if I combined my feature matrix (edited post to show matrix I am trying to train), it would just mess up the advantage of each distinct feature values and the ml algorithm would have a really difficult time understand these values and would not train very well.

Comment: For example, I cannot combine my direction and speed features together because that would mess up the positive and negative signs (where both indicate if feature point the moving north-east, north-west, south-east, or south-west from previous position). Any smart way of combining these features?

Comment: So you want to combine direction and speed features into a single feature, and this is the reason why you choose a 4D matrix? I am not sure whether I understand your data here, but I would try to just treat all those directions as categorical variable and make them numeric dummy variables.

Comment: The reason that I chose a 4D matrix because I need the two features, direction and speed between facial landmarks. Then I need to add a dimension since there is a certain number of frames per video (3D so far). Then I need to label the entire set of frames as one emotion (basically label the entire video as happy, sad, etc) which makes it a 4D matrix. I edited my post above to help you understand how the matrix is made. And what do you mean by making them a categorial variable and make the others dummy variables?

Comment: This is the structure of the matrix: "2 videos (each having an emotion label), 17 frames per video, 68 facial landmarks, 2 features (direction and speed)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81715/discussion-between-user3377126-and-jianxun-li).

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from your example which is the sample axis. But training in sklearn can be done like this (if the first axis is your sample axis):

```
model.fit(features.reshape(len(features), -1), labels)
```

There is no benefit in knowing the 4D structure for any sklearn classifiers. The adopted standard throughout the package, to ensure simplicity and clarity, is to have the first matrix dimension enumerate the examples and the second one the features. So in your case, you need to ravel the 3 remaining feature dimensions into one long vector.

Comment: I was considering on just combining the three features into one vector, but the problem is that if I combined my feature matrix (edited post to show matrix I am trying to train), it would just mess up the advantage of each distinct feature values and the ml algorithm would have a really difficult time understand these values and would not train very well.

Comment: For example, I cannot combine my direction and speed features together because that would mess up the positive and negative signs (where both indicate if feature point the moving north-east, north-west, south-east, or south-west from previous position). Any smart way of combining these features?